# Nested CSS not loading with Next JS

Tags: css, next.js

CSS is working only if I define:

```css
classname {
  color: white;
}
```

But, its not working if I define:

```css
classname1 classname2 {
  color: white;
}
```

I have created a global stylesheet and imported that in _app.js file.

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import { store } from "../redux/store";
import "bulma";
import Layout from "../components/layout/layout";

const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default store.withRedux(MyApp);
```

Could you please help me to fix this?

Thank You.

Comment: How are you using the classes?

Comment: In CSS or NextJS?

Comment: Next.js, I mean are you using it in CSS modules, styled-components, or global stylesheet... And how are you doing that? Show us something that we can reproduce it at our end. There are many ways some style can be applied to an element, we just want to know how are you doing that. First refer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have created a global stylesheet and imported that in _app.js file.

Comment: I have updated the question with full info.

Comment: You have still not added how you are using it. For `.foo .bar {...}` to work, your structure should be like `<el1 className="foo">...<el2 className="bar">...</el2>...</el1>`, i.e., element with class `bar` must be child of element having `foo`.